# Compose Navigation destination animation transitions by conditional

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, android-transitions, back-stack, navcontroller

For certain destination screens, I would like a certain transition animations to happen only when navigating to or from certain other destinations.

For example, when navigating to and from Category screen from the bottom Nav bar, I would like to have no or default animation transition, but if I'm navigating to a sub-screen of Category screen, ie by clicking on an item, I would like slide animation.

How can I write a conditional in my exitTransition/popEnterTransition/popExitTransition to check:
a. the screen I am navigating to
b. the screen that was just popped

Checking navController's backstack can't work since the previous screen is already popped.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am running into the same problem!

Comment: "exitTransition/popEnterTransition/popExitTransition" are lambdas (functions) and those lambdas can dynamically return one or another Transition based on your conditions.